# R programming, r bind messes up order of input

Tags: r, rbind

I have R function that

- takes in directory name (where this directory has numbered .csv files)
- takes in a particular set of numbers that represents the files
- combines the said files into a dataframe
- prints out the number of occurrences for a particular ID

#### Function

```
library(plyr)

complete <- function(directory, id=1:5){

  files_full <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  working_set <- files_full [id]
  seethis <- lapply(working_set, read.csv)
  output <- do.call(rbind, seethis)

  no_na <- na.omit(output)
  new_df <- as.data.frame(no_na)
  new_output <- count(new_df,"ID")
  colnames(new_output) <- c("id", "Occurrences")
  new_output
}
```

#### Question

If I invoke function with

```
complete("diet_data",c(4,3,2))
```

I get this output

```
  id Occurrences
1  2          30
2  3          17
3  4          30
```

But I wish to retain the id order, i.e. 4, 3, 2 so that output is

```
  id Occurrences
1  4          30
2  3          17
3  2          30
```

How to do this? And there is no way to tell if id will be 1:5, 5:3, etc

And a sample dataframe from this function would look something like this

```
structure(list(ID = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Age = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), Weight = c(188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 
189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 190L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 
192L, 192L, 192L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 
175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 177L, 210L, 209L, 
209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 208L, 
207L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 205L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 
203L, 203L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 201L), Day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L)), .Names = c("ID", "Age", "Weight", 
"Day"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(47:59, .Names = c("47", 
"48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", 
"59"), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: anyway you can add a line like `new_df$ID <- with(new_df, factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))` before you do your `count` or you can skip the count function altogether and make a table `data.frame(with(new_df, table(factor(ID, levels = unique(ID)))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this line at the end of your function

```
sorted_output <- new_output[match(id, new_output$ID),]
```